# Error with Newtonsoft.Json: an item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, json.net, signalr

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json with signalR to send data to client side. The following code takes data from database and is supposed to send it but it gives the exception:

```
an item with the same key has already been added
```

The code is:

```
using Makbin.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace Makbin.Web.Hubs
{
    public class LogBackgroundTicker : IRegisteredObject
    {
        private readonly MakbinRepository _repository;      
        private Timer logsTimer;
        private IHubContext hub;

        public LogBackgroundTicker()
        {
            _repository = new MakbinRepository();

            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

            hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<LogHub>();

            logsTimer = new Timer(OnLogsTimerElapsed, null,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
        }

        private void OnLogsTimerElapsed(object sender)
        {
            var result = _repository.Syslog.Select(x => x).Take(300);
            var finalResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        {
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                        });
            hub.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), finalResult);
        }

        public void Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            logsTimer.Dispose();

            HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is Syslog class:

```
public class Syslog
    {
        public Guid LogId { get; set; }
        public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Facility { get; set; }
        public string Severity { get; set; }
        public string DevTime { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public virtual Peripherals Peripheral { get; set; }
    }
```

how can I fix this exception?

Comment: Apparently you have some sort of dictionary and trying to have duplicate entries... But it is impossible to suggest anything as you did not provide [MCVE].

Comment: No I haven't,  I provided Syslog class

Comment: What does your JSON data look like? As Alexei said, the error indicates that the JSON data has duplicate property names in it.

Comment: I agree that you have not provided complete verifiable example. Now why would not you do so if you are looking for help? BTW, I would blame your repository firsts and JSON.Net second for the exception (which is as good as any other suggestion as there is no call stack or even line for exception shown).

Comment: As you see I updated the question. Now for more elaboration, I should say it works in the first iteration (because backgroundTicker runs every 7 seconds) but on the second call of the OnLogsTimerElapsed it throws this exception

Comment: `Select(x => x)` doesn't do anything. Do you also get the error when you use `Take(2)` or maybe even `Take(1)`?

Comment: There is no difference again the same error.

Comment: Show full stack trace.